# Bash: How to repeat the same prompt and record all answer that has been inputted?

Tags: bash

I'm noob, My goal is to create a list of all files in some different directories that may contain space character on Linux OS. I need a program that ask the same prompt for the infinite number of directory, one by one. And then, list of all that files by using "find" command.

My beginner bash script for three different directories goes like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo enter your path, for example /home/user/My Documents
read path1
echo enter your next path
read path2
echo enter your next path
read path3

#I want this program to keep asking "enter your next path" until We blank the answer and then We hit enter

find "$path1" "$path2" "$path3" -type f
```

I want the result of "find" command to be able to list all files from all directories that has been inputted.

Sorry for my bad english. Thank you

Comment: what's wrong with what you have? use `set -vx` on cmd-line to see what values are being used for your variables. Your english is better that some "natives" ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My code was not applicable for other number of directories. Let's say We have 1, 10, or even 100 directories... I can't think any solutions other than changing the code. I need program that always applicable for every number of directories without changing the code.

Comment: You need a loop.  In your loop you ask for the next directory to verify.  When they have entered all the values they want, ask them to type "done" or "end".  Your loop keeps going until the response is "done" or "end".  Then you run your find with the directories they put in the loop.  Since you are new to this, look at https://www.shellcheck.net/, it will help you find syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you agree to enter one path per line and to finish the input with a blank line, you could try:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

declare -a path_array

while true; do
  read -r -p "Enter a path: " path
  if [ -z "$path" ] ; then
    break;
  fi
  path_array+=("$path")
done
find "${path_array[@]}" -type f
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That code is exactly what i want. I will learn more about loop